# Reminding someone to send me their resume?

Tags: united-states, relationships, referral

My company is looking to hire and I told a former classmate (I'll call him Jake) about it since I feel he is qualified. He sounded interested in the position (it would be in a different department than mine), and we talked for a bit on the phone about the position & the company overall. He wasn't 100% sure about relocating (which he'd have to do for this job), but the conversation ended on a very positive note and Jake told me he'd send me his resume shortly.

It's been nearly a week already and I haven't gotten anything. As far as I know, Jake is not *actively* looking for a job, but on the phone he did say that he is very much open to new things (and I'd guess that he has even browsed around online a bit).

I found out today that my company is mid-process of interviewing a few candidates this week for the same position. Knowing how it goes in my company, Jake needs to get his resume in asap if he wants to get a fair chance before one of the other candidates gets hired.

I don't want to pressure him if he has decided he's not interested, but I do want to make sure he has a good chance at the job if he *is* interested.

**Should I send him a note telling him about the timeline that I am foreseeing, or just forget about it unless he sends me his resume?**

*Other background info:*

I told him to send me his resume rather than applying online, since referrals get taken with 4X the amount of seriousness compared to a seemingly-random application through the online portal.

Although Jake & I used to be classmates, we've been out of touch for a while (and never had a real friendship either). He's much more of an acquaintance than a friend or coworker, so it's possible that he might feel uncomfortable telling me outright that he has changed his mind and is no longer interested.

Comment: A small reminder doesn't hurt anyone. Jake may not be interested, no harm done. If he is interested and got busy or thought there was more time or wanted to brush up his resume ( as he is not actively looking for a job), it may help. Either way, it will be nice of you to send a reminder.

Comment: Sounds like Jake is doing what I would do in his situation, say he isn’t interested, even though he isn’t to keep his friend.  His actions speak louder than his words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just drop a simple reminder,

> The post I talked about is coming to an end soon, are you still interested?

This way if he wants to apply he can still send it in and he has been reminded, if not he'll likely either ignore you or just say no.